# Connect via ssh to see folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, tunnel

I use the following repo to connect  via ssh to some system.

I was able to do it ,( I got client ready and on data event )

Now I want to see the folders of the app which I do ssh to it ,
any idea how I can do it ?

when I use the ssh **via command line** I was able to connect to the app 
and simple by doing `ls` I can see the application folders etc

I use the following repo and this sample code

https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2

```
var conn = new Client();

conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');

  conn.shell(function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;

    stream.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Stream :: close');

      conn.end();
    }).on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });

    stream.end('ls -l\nexit\n');
  });
}).connect({
  host: '192.168.100.100',
  port: 22,
  username: 'frylock',
  privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('/here/is/my/key')
});
```

Comment: `( I got client ready and on data event )`  So what did the on data event say?.

Comment: @Keith - OUT Client :: ready    OUT STDOUT:  14:44:17 up 14 days, 21:55,  0 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.15, 0.12

Comment: You should use SFTP instead of plain SSH.

Comment: That output does not match your code (which is copied verbatim from an example in the readme). I suspect that output is from one of the other examples in the readme.

Comment: I've not used this module, but too me it looks like the code above is sending the `ls -l` before the server is ready,.  What might be better is to wait until you get the first `STDOUT:` and then send the `ls -l`